# How do I dereference a namespace name in my launch file?

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the name of my namespace in my launch file, to do some more things, but for that, I would have to dereference my namespace name in the launch file like we dereference arguments using `$(arg argument_name)`

Any idea how this can be done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382015/how-do-i-dereference-a-namespace-name-in-my-launch-file-?/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2021-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @electrophod

How about using the [Group](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/group) option that provides the XML launch. Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <arg name="ns0" default="ares"/> <!-- Namespace 0 -->
  <arg name="ns1" default="ares"/> <!-- Namespace 1 -->

  <!-- Group namespace 0 Nodes -->
  <group ns="$(arg ns0)">
    <!-- Include nodes that works in namespace 0 -->
    <include...>
    ...
    </include>
  </group>

  <!-- Include nodes that works in global namespace -->
  <include...>
  ...
  </include>

  <!-- Group namespace 1 Nodes -->
  <group ns="$(arg ns1)">
    <!-- Include nodes that works in namespace 1 -->
    <include...>
    ...
    </include>
  </group>

</launch>
```

And call it like this:

```
roslaunch package my_launch.launch ns0:=namespace_0 ns1:=namespace_1
```

I do not know if that is exactly what you want, if it not the case I will update the answer.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-08**:
In my experience, it is rarely necessary to parameterize the namespace string. If you use the  tag, the namespaces will naturally nest, without the developer doing anything further.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2021-07-08**:
@Mike Scheutzow I guess so, but maybe it is an interesting way of organizing your worspaces, for intance let us imagine that we need to work with a fleet of vehicles which is lanched and controlled concurrently with the same architecture.